# Incompatible types in interface with parameterization

Tags: java, gwt

try to implement parameterization in such example:

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import name.pehl.piriti.xml.client.XmlReader;
import name.pehl.piriti.xml.client.XmlWriter;

public interface XmlPiritiService<T>
{
   public interface Reader extends XmlReader<T>
   {
   }

   public interface Writer extends XmlWriter<T>
   {
   }

   public static final Reader READER = GWT.create(Reader.class);
   public static final Writer WRITER = GWT.create(Writer.class);
}

import gwt.client.common.client.pirity.XmlPiritiService;
import name.pehl.piriti.commons.client.Path;

public class ResultsModel implements XmlPiritiService<ResultsModel>
{
   @Path("TotalCount")
   private int totalCount;

   public int getTotalCount()
   {
      return totalCount;
   }

   public void setTotalCount(int totalCount)
   {
      this.totalCount = totalCount;
   }
}
```

Then I try to use method read() of XmlReader from the static variable:
  ResultsModel resultsModel = ResultsModel.READER.read(response.getText());

There a have an incompatible types.
Required: ResultsModel
Found: T

What I am do wrong with parametrization stuff?

Thanks

Comment: How is `ResultsModel.READER` even compiling?

Comment: No, event IDE don't allow and show this error: "Incompatible types. Required: ResultsModel Found: T"
Thanks

Comment: `public interface Reader extends XmlReader<T>` should not be valid. Nested interfaces are implicitly static, and can't make use of outer type parameters like that.

Comment: Is it possible to implement it with  parametrization stuff otherwise?
Thanks.

Comment: It would need to be `public interface Reader<T> extends XmlReader<T>` or `public interface Reader extends XmlReader<SomeClass>`.